# jQuery image carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, html5

I have made this custom image carousel, using HTML5, jQuery and CSS. My aim was to make it really *lightweight* but with (just) enough features: "bullets", auto-advance, responsiveness.

```js
var $elm = $('.slider'),
  $slidesContainer = $elm.find('.slides-container'),
  slides = $slidesContainer.children('a'),
  slidesCount = slides.length,
  slideHeight = $(slides[0]).find('img').outerHeight(false),
  animationspeed = 1500,
  animationInterval = 7000;

var shuffle = function(slides) {
  var j, x, i;
  for (i = slides.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    x = slides[i];
    slides[i] = slides[j];
    slides[j] = x;
  }
  return slides;
}

shuffle(slides);

// Set (initial) z-index for each slide
var setZindex = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slidesCount; i++) {
    $(slides[i]).css('z-index', slidesCount - i);
  }
};
setZindex();

var setActiveSlide = function() {
  $(slides).removeClass('active');
  $(slides[activeIdx]).addClass('active');
};

var advanceFunc = function() {
  if ($('.slider-nav li.activeSlide').index() + 1 != $('.slider-nav li').length) {
    $('.slider-nav li.activeSlide').next().find('a').trigger('click');
  } else {
    $('.slider-nav li:first').find('a').trigger('click');
  }
}

var autoAdvance = setInterval(advanceFunc, animationInterval);

//Set slide height
$(slides).css('height', slideHeight);

// Append bullets
if (slidesCount > 1) {
  /* Prepend the slider navigation to the slider
     if there are at least 2 slides */
  $elm.prepend('<ul class="slider-nav"></ul>');

  // make a bullet for each slide
  for (var i = 0; i < slidesCount; i++) {
    var bullets = '<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
    if (i == 0) {
      // active bullet
      var bullets = '<li class="activeSlide"><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
      // active slide
      $(slides[0]).addClass('active');
    }
    $('.slider-nav').append(bullets);
  }
};

var Queue = function() {
  var lastPromise = null;

  this.add = function(callable) {
    var methodDeferred = $.Deferred();
    var queueDeferred = this.setup();
    // execute next queue method
    queueDeferred.done(function() {

      // call actual method and wrap output in deferred
      callable().then(methodDeferred.resolve)
    });
    lastPromise = methodDeferred.promise();
  };

  this.setup = function() {
    var queueDeferred = $.Deferred();
    // when the previous method returns, resolve this one
    $.when(lastPromise).always(function() {
      queueDeferred.resolve();
    });
    return queueDeferred.promise();
  }
};

var queue = new Queue();
var slideUpDown = function(previousIdx, activeIdx) {
  queue.add(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // set top property for all the slides
      $(slides).not(slides[previousIdx]).css('top', slideHeight);
      // then animate to the next slide
      $(slides[activeIdx]).animate({
        'top': 0
      }, animationspeed);

      $(slides[previousIdx]).animate({
        'top': "-100%"
      }, animationspeed, 'swing', resolve);
    })
  })
};

var previousIdx = '0' // First slide
$('.slider-nav a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  activeIdx = $(this).text();

  // Disable clicling on an active item
  if ($(slides[activeIdx]).hasClass("active")) {
    return false;
  }
  $('.slider-nav a').closest('li').removeClass('activeSlide');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('activeSlide');

  // Reset autoadvance if user clicks bullet
  if (event.originalEvent !== undefined) {
    clearInterval(autoAdvance);
    autoAdvance = setInterval(advanceFunc, animationInterval);
  }

  setActiveSlide();
  slideUpDown(previousIdx, activeIdx);
  previousIdx = activeIdx
});
```

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slider .slider-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.slider .slider-nav a {
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  line-height: 4px;
}

.slider .slider-nav li.activeSlide {
  background: #fff;
}

.slider .slider-nav li.activeSlide a {
  display: none;
}

.slider .slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider .slides-container a {
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.slider .slides-container img {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Di6.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR2uJ.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zynhv.jpg">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9BgN.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works fine but I am certain it can be optimized: the same result can be achieved with *less code*. I am not thinking of a complete rewrite, but of ditching redundant and useless code.

The carousel's current architecture requires the slides to have *z-indexes* which I wish I could get rid of. What would be a good *alternative* to that?

See a jsFiddle **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ajax30/vk0cLw6b/embedded/result/)**.

Please help me make it better. Thanks!

Comment: Is the queue with promises supposed to prevent the slides from moving too quickly or some other purpose?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Yes, this is the purpose.

Comment: Why do you believe z-indexes need to be set? The snippet in [the first version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/203084/1) (without those set) appears to function the same as the snippet in the current version...

Comment: After getting an answer you are not allowed to change your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). Refer to [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114) for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General Feedback

The carousel appears to work acceptably. The code is a bit scattered. Consider the variable `activeIdx`. It appears to be set in the click handler and referenced in the function `setActiveSlide()` as a global variable - not as a parameter, but in `slideUpDown()` it is a parameter.

I'm not convinced the promise queue is absolutely necessary. Perhaps a simple [debounced function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) would suffice.

And there are a lot of repeated DOM queries - remember those are not cheap! Especially in the function `advanceFunc()`. Instead of querying the DOM so many times, it would be better to store the list items (A.K.A. `bullets`) in a variable after they are added and re-use them in `advanceFunc()`. [Modulus division](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) can then be used to determine the next index.

### Specific critique

#### bullet creation

The name of the variable `bullets` is a bit misleading for a single element. A singular name like `bullet` would be more appropriate.

And to create each bullet, the [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) could be used. So instead of manually constructing the HTML for the list items:

> ```
> var bullets = '<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
> if (i == 0) {
>   // active bullet
>   var bullets = '<li class="activeSlide"><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>';
> ```

use `$('<li>')` for the bullet and [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) to set the inner HTML:

```
var bullet = $('<li>').html('<a href="#">' + i + '</a>');
```

Then the class name can be added via [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass)

```
if (i == 0) {
  $(slides[0]).addClass('active');
  bullet.addClass('activeSlide');
```

That way the inner HTML is only specified once.

#### Shuffle function return value unused

There is no need to return `slides` at the end of `shuffle()`:

> ```
> return slides;
> ```

This is because the return value is not assigned to anything (unless you intended for that to be the case):

> ```
> shuffle(slides);
> ```

### Rewrite

See the modified code below. It doesn't use the queue or promises at all, and as far as I can tell maintains the same functionality. I also made `previousIdx` and `activeIdx` variables outside the functions instead of parameters. Because of this, I wrapped the whole thing in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to avoid adding those variables to the global scope.

```js
$(function() {
  var $elm = $('.slider'),
    $slidesContainer = $elm.find('.slides-container'),
    slides = $slidesContainer.children('a'),
    slidesCount = slides.length,
    slideHeight = $(slides[0]).find('img').outerHeight(false),
    animationspeed = 1500,
    animationInterval = 7000;

  var activeIdx = 0;
  var previousIdx = 0; // First slide
  var shuffle = function(slides) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = slides.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      x = slides[i];
      slides[i] = slides[j];
      slides[j] = x;
    }
    return slides;
  }
  shuffle(slides);

  // Set (initial) z-index for each slide
  var setZindex = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < slidesCount; i++) {
      $(slides[i]).css('z-index', slidesCount - i);
    }
  };
  setZindex();

  var setActiveSlide = function() {
    $(slides).removeClass('active');
    $(slides[activeIdx]).addClass('active');
    $(bullets).removeClass('activeSlide');
    $(bullets[activeIdx]).addClass('activeSlide');
  };

  function showSlideAtActiveIndex(resetInterval) {
    setActiveSlide();
    slideUpDown(); //previousIdx, activeIdx);
    previousIdx = activeIdx;
  }

  var advanceFunc = function() {
    activeIdx = ++activeIdx % slidesCount;
    showSlideAtActiveIndex();
  }

  var autoAdvance = setInterval(advanceFunc, animationInterval);

  //Set slide height
  $(slides).css('height', slideHeight);

  // Append bullets
  if (slidesCount > 1) {
    /* Prepend the slider navigation to the slider
       if there are at least 2 slides */
    $elm.prepend('<ul class="slider-nav"></ul>');

    // make a bullet for each slide
    for (var i = 0; i < slidesCount; i++) {
      var bullet = $('<li>').html('<a href="#">' + i + '</a>');
      if (i == 0) {
        bullet.addClass('activeSlide');
        // active bullet
        // active slide
        $(slides[0]).addClass('active');
      }
      $('.slider-nav').append(bullet);
    }
  };
  var bullets = $('.slider-nav li');

  var slideUpDown = function() {
    $(slides).not(slides[previousIdx]).css('top', slideHeight);
    // then animate to the next slide
    $(slides[activeIdx]).animate({
      'top': 0
    }, animationspeed);
    $(slides[previousIdx]).animate({
      'top': "-100%"
    }, animationspeed, 'swing');
  };

  $('.slider-nav a').on('click', function(event) {
    var clickedIdx = $(this).text();
    if ($(slides[clickedIdx]).hasClass("active")) {
      return false;
    }
    activeIdx = clickedIdx;
    showSlideAtActiveIndex(); 
    clearInterval(autoAdvance);
    setTimeout(function() {
      autoAdvance = setInterval(advanceFunc, animationInterval);
    }, animationInterval);
  });
});
```

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slider .slider-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 1px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.slider .slider-nav a {
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  line-height: 4px;
}

.slider .slider-nav li.activeSlide {
  background: #fff;
}

.slider .slider-nav li.activeSlide a {
  display: none;
}

.slider .slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider .slides-container a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.slider .slides-container img {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=east" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=south" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=west" alt="">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=north" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Feel free to improve my version. This is the reason it is posted here. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, click the second bullet of the carousel **[on your site](http://samonela.scienceontheweb.net/jQuery/imageCarousel2.html)** and you will see that the second slide replaces the first  instantly, with no transition.

Comment: The `shuffle(slides);` line "randomizes" the slides.

Comment: Okay I added a modified snippet. I understand the point of `shuffle()` but am stating that there is no need for `return slides;` at the end

Comment: It seems to *look* and *behave* differently: the slides do not advance one after the other (does this happen in the snippet window *only*?). Also, the z-indexes are still there.

Comment: Strange - in my browser console I see Errors: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR`... But [in the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samonela/yksv6472/51/) it appears to work...

Comment: Please try an anwer for the question *[Unidirectional Bootstrap 3 carousel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207554/unidirectional-bootstrap-3-carousel)*. Thanks!

Comment: I think I mentioned this in the past - while you accepted the answer and the bounty was awarded to it, would you consider voting on this and any other answer you receive? Otherwise the questions might not technically be considered [answered](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/30/ok-now-define-answered/).