# Unidirectional Bootstrap 3 carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a custom Bootstrap 3 carousel, with vertical, unidirectional, slide transitions.

I want to prevent slide transitions from overlapping when the bullets are clicked in random order and rapid succession.

I came up with this solution that relies on *disabling them as long as a slide transition is in progress*, then enabling them between transitions:

```js
var carouselDuration = function() {
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION = 1000;
}

carouselDuration();
// While a transition is in progress (slide event), do this
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $indicator = $(this).find('.carousel-indicators>li');
    $indicator.css('pointer-events', 'none');
});

// While a transition has finished (slid event), do this
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $indicator = $(this).find('.carousel-indicators>li');
    $indicator.css('pointer-events', 'auto');
});
```

```css
.carousel.vertical {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item {
  width: auto;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.right {
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active.left {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators li {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url("https://grgs.ro/1/i/sprite.png") no-repeat -528px -502px;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-position: -528px -524px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel vertical slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=east" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=south" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=west" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Still, I am looking for a **queuing** mechanism, as it is more natural and elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Feedback

The code seems fairly concise, though I do have suggestions below that can simplify it even more. I was hoping there was some class name applied to the element with class *carousel* during the slide transition but apparently the bootstrap code does not do that, though you could use the event callback functions to apply a class name yourself. That way the CSS style for `pointer-events` can be moved into the CSS.

Because the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method accepts multiple events separated by a space, you can use one call for both events, and a single [Partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) to call the [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method, which will add and then remove a class to the carousel element:

```
var carouselCollection = $('#myCarousel');
carouselCollection.on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', 
    carouselCollection.toggleClass.bind(carouselCollection, 'sliding'));
```

Then the CSS can contain the style:

```
.carousel.vertical.sliding .carousel-indicators li {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

See that working in the rewritten code below.

I don't see much point in creating the function `carouselDuration()` and calling it immediately afterwards but then never again. Why not just move that single line out where it is called? I could see a point in doing that after some condition is met (e.g. DOM ready, jQuery/carousel ready, etc).

Some of the CSS rulesets are a bit redundant. For instance, some of the `top: 0` rulesets should be cascadable from `.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item` and apply to the next three subsequent selectors.

Also, I believe I was able to remove this block without any adverse affects. Are there really elements with class `.right` and `.left` or are those for the left/right controls that aren't being used?

> ```
> .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next,
> .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev,
> .carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.right {
>   transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
>   top: 0;
> }
> ```

### Suggestions

It would likely help to define that value for the duration as a constant (and if you are using [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) then use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)) at the top of the code, so it can be easily modified in the future if necessary.

---

While there are only a couple redundant DOM queries (e.g. `$(#myCarousel)`) it would be wise to cache those in a variable.

---

The event handler functions are very redundant, and violate the **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself principle.  The only thing that appears to change is the value assigned to the CSS style *pointer-events*. If the approach mentioned above with the `.toggleClass()` method doesn't work, the common code in the two callback functions could be abstracted into a single function that accepts the value for that CSS style, and then [Partially applied functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) could be created with [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to fix the value to apply to the style.

```
var carouselCollection = $('#myCarousel');

function setPointerEventsOnListItems(value, e) {
  var $indicator = carouselCollection.find('.carousel-indicators>li');
  $indicator.css('pointer-events', value);
}
// While a transition is in progress (slide event), do this
carouselCollection.on('slide.bs.carousel', setPointerEventsOnListItems.bind(null, 'none'));

// While a transition has finished (slid event), do this
carouselCollection.on('slid.bs.carousel', setPointerEventsOnListItems.bind(null, 'auto'));
```

---

As you likely know, the [jQuery DOM ready function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3) would be good to use so as to avoid accidentally accessing the DOM before it is ready (though that isn't a problem as much nowdays with modern browsers and adding the script tags to the end of the `<body>`). An [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) could also be used instead of that jQuery DOM ready callback.

---

### Rewritten code

The code below utilizes the advice above, though utilizes the `.toggleClass()` method.

```js
var DURATION = 1000; //could use const instead of var if supporting es-6
$(function() { //DOM ready callback
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION = DURATION;
  var carouselCollection = $('#myCarousel');
  // While a transition is in progress (slide event), do this
  carouselCollection.on('slide.bs.carousel slid.bs.carousel', carouselCollection.toggleClass.bind(carouselCollection, 'sliding'));
});
```

```css
.carousel.vertical {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.item {
  width: auto;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.prev.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.next.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner>.active.left {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators li {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url("https://grgs.ro/1/i/sprite.png") no-repeat -528px -502px;
}

.carousel.vertical.sliding .carousel-indicators li {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel.vertical .carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-position: -528px -524px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel vertical slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=east" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=south" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/300/?gravity=west" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the feedback and the effort to rewrite the code. Can you help with the queuing mechanism or some *other* solution that would make the slider more user-friendly, meaning the the user would not have to click (temporarily) *inactive bullets*?

Comment: Please provide an answer to the topic **[An improvable use case of the Swiper slider](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208516/an-improvable-use-case-of-the-swiper-slider)**. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you don’t get the wrong impression about this site, though maybe you have, since many answers offer a rewrite- especially easy with questions involving JS because snippets make it simple for demonstrating. Requests for code implementations are off-topic for this site.